# How do I work with LUIS's timex daterange in C#?

Tags: c#, azure-language-understanding

In [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-prebuilt-datetimev2#date-range-resolution-examples-for-day-of-week) example, Microsoft shows "tuesday to thursday" being recognized by LUIS, which responds with a start and date time. However, when I use the same example with my LUIS, it doesn't send me start or end dates. it just sends me a timex string, which I don't see any documentation on how to convert it to start and end dates in C#, unless I create my own parser, which is like a whole different project for me that I'm sure Microsoft's already done. This is what LUIS returns

```json
{
  "$instance": {
    "datetime": [
      {
        "startIndex": 17,
        "endIndex": 41,
        "text": "from tuesday to thursday",
        "type": "builtin.datetimeV2.daterange"
      }
    ]
  },
  "datetime": [
    {
      "type": "daterange",
      "timex": [
        "(XXXX-WXX-2,XXXX-WXX-4,P2D)"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

On the last line, it gives a string with a bunch of `X`s. Why didn't they give start and end time like in the demo? How can I get that? Microsoft also [mentions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-prebuilt-datetimev2#json-property-descriptions) there's a `resolution` property. I don't receive that resolution property by LUIS.

Comment: Have you tried the *exact* phrase as given in the example?  "Tuesday to Thursday" can be interpreted differently than "FROM Tuesday to Thursday".

Answer (score 1):

What is the entire entity section of the response? You should ensure that you are using a datetimev2 entity in your LUIS model, and that it is trained. If all that is done, I'm not sure why it is not responding with a resolution. It should. Does it fail in the test panel? Like you linked [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-prebuilt-datetimev2#date-range-resolution-examples-for-day-of-week), it should come back with an entity of type datetimev2.daterange, and then should have the resolution.

The timex format only shows the portions that are resolved. It shows that it is a range ([P2D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). period, two days) from [Tuesday](https://github.com/microsoft/Recognizers-Text/blob/e687deccc526daaadd72584f777ba2b93e2d16fc/Patterns/English/English-DateTime.yaml#L759) (2) to [Thursday](https://github.com/microsoft/Recognizers-Text/blob/e687deccc526daaadd72584f777ba2b93e2d16fc/Patterns/English/English-DateTime.yaml#L764) (4). That's how the timex value should look. You, can find an example on how to use the resolvers in the timex sample [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/40.timex-resolution/Resolution.cs).

Answer (score 0):

The LUIS response should contain the resolution you need.
But if you really need to manipulate the timex expression to re-resolve, you can re-use the same library as LUIS uses to recognize/resolve datetimes.

https://github.com/microsoft/Recognizers-Text

You can use it's timex resolver or re-interpret the entity in the original sentence.